# Tax is not added to grand total in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento

1. I create `tax zone` in **Sales->Tax->Manage tax Zone & Rate**
   [image]
2. I create `Tax Rule` in **Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rule**
   [image]
3. I apply `Tax Rules` in **System->Configuration->Sales->Tax**
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   I make sure that the `Tax Class of the product is Taxable Good.`

But the issue is when I select  `postcode` under `Billing Information`  the `tax` is not added to the `Grand total`.
The `cart page` and `checkout page` not showing the `tax`

**cart page**
[image]

**checkout page**
[image]

Comment: Are you sure Chair is taxable good?

Comment: @DavidTay: yes..sure